# Asmx webservice IP Address change issue due to hosting in internet

Tags: flex3, asmx, windows-firewall

I have a asmx webservice which is accessed from office intranet. I could consume through my flex app with the local IP Address of the hosted system. When that particular system was exposed to the internet, the external IP got changed. Now If I use the same flex app using exposed URL, the wsdl is not getting loaded. Reason being the WSDL is accessed using the outbound IP and the request was trying to route to the intranet IP. The Intranet IP being not exposed, gives a webservice load error.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should always use a named route and not an IP address.

you should use something like 
webservices.your_domain.com

When you are in development, you edit you hosts file so that this address will be routed to the local IP, when you are in production the DNS will route to the real URL.

Never, Never use an IP, this is not best case, and you can have many errors with it.